# any actionscript exception that will not cause the flash player to pop up a dialog?

Tags: flash, exception, actionscript

Till now all the exceptions in my code will cause the host flash player to pop up a window to say there is an exception and the execution will be paused, I am wondering is there any exception/abnormal things that will be detected by flash player but not be popped up?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Edit: I think I misunderstood the point of your question:]**
If you have an error handler set up to handle the error then it shouldn't throw up a popup alert in the debugging player. That alert comes up as a result of unhandled errors (I think - can someone correct me if I'm wrong?). The upshot is that you might get errors that don't throw up an alert if the AS3 code knows to look for them.

[...original post follows]
Flash Player 10.1 (currently in beta) allows you to define a global error handler. In theory, this should allow you to listen for all errors that may crop up at runtime and handle them quietly, without generating an alert window in the debugging player.

If you're interested, the 10.1 beta is here: http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplayer10/

Let us know if that works out for you! :)

Answer (score 2):

only debug flash player shows these errors/exceptions. And as far as, hiding these kind of pop-ups from user, then one should always catch all the possible errors/exceptions within `try...catch` block. And Errors/Exceptions are supposed to pop-up when they occurs, so there is no `DoNotPopThisError` in flash.

Comment: So your answer is there is no case that exception not be pop up in the debug flash player? Actually I encountered the problem that there is no pop up in debug flash player but the host c# program crashes because of the "exception"(I don't know whether is exception though)